# Bazel error on Win: command is longer than CreateProcessW's limit (32767 characters)

Tags: bazel

I'm using bazel (4.0.0) to build my project.
During linking stage I get the error saying `command is longer than CreateProcessW's limit (32767 characters)`.
I found not much about this problem, tried to add *feature* in my *cc_toolchain_config.bzl* like `linker_param_file_feature` (s. in this [cc_toolchain_config.bzl](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/cpp/unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl)) using

```
flag_group(
    flags = ["%{libraries_to_link.object_files}"],
    iterate_over = "libraries_to_link.object_files",
    expand_if_equal = variable_with_value(
        name = "libraries_to_link.type",
        value = "object_file_group",
    ),
),
```

but without a solution.

Linker command line is:

```
SUBCOMMAND: # //do-it [action 'Linking elf-to-gen.elf', configuration: 123456789abcdefg, execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host]
cd C:/users/abc/execroot/pmanager
  SET PATH=C:\the-path\.......
    SET PWD=/proc/self/cwd
    SET RUNFILES_MANIFEST_ONLY=1
  c:/../linker.exe -o bazel-out/../bin/elf-to-gen.elf
  [List of paths of around 400 object files]
  [linker options]
  [path-to-linker-directives-file.ld]
```

Because I cannot find any solution for this, maybe it is solved already but I do not see it? Or I'm the only one using bazel and having right now the problem?

Comment: You tagged your message with irrelevant tags. Use only bazel. Remove extra ones.

Comment: You should tell in which line bazel triggers the error you have. Is it to run the compiler, the linker of something else. I understand it is the linker. What is the linker used, what looks the command like?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `output_user_root` as explained here: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/windows.html#avoid-long-path-issues ?

Comment: Yes @dms. I tried to set `startup --output_user_root=C:/tmp` in file `.bazelrc` but did not solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution...
In the *BUILD* file, there for the *cc_toolchain*, the *support_param_file* was set to "0".
Don't know why. Default is "True".
Set to "True" or just remove it works fine now.